# Triangulating a 3d point

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm by no means a mathematician, and this is my first post, but hopefully this isn't too complex.

I want to learn about triangulation. If I set up two cameras and take an image of one single object, I can deduce two 2d points from the two images. I can also figure out any information needed about the camera (distance between them, field of view, etc).

With that info, how do I figure out the 3d point? I'm familiar with 2d/3d projection (done a lot of 3d graphics) but I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are the two pointing angles of the cameras and their relative positions.  Let one camera be at the origin, $+z$ be up and $+x$ be east.  If you measure elevation relative to the $xy$ plane and azimuth as the angle clockwise from north as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system) (there are other conventions), the target point will be along the line $t(\sin(\text{elevation}_1) \sin(\text{azimuth}_1), \sin (\text{elevation}_1) \cos (\text{azimuth}_1), \cos (\text{elevation}_1))$.  Then if the second camera is at position $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ it gives you a line $s(\sin(\text{elevation}_2) \sin(\text{azimuth}_2), \sin (\text{elevation}_2) \cos (\text{azimuth}_2), \cos (\text{elevation}_2))+(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

These have to agree, so you can solve for $s,t$ and get the coordinates.  A similar analysis works if you get the angle data in a different format.

Comment: Thanks, two questions:

* What units is `elevation`? How do measure it? From the Y coordinate in the image?

* What is considered north for the azimuth angle?

Comment: @JamesLong:  elevation can be in whatever units you want-the trig functions have to agree.  I took +y as north for the azimuth angle, as you can see by plugging in azimuth=0 and noting that y is maximum.